# WCF - Execution order of parameter inspectors

Tags: c#, wcf

We have implemented custom attributes for validations which implements IParameterInspector and IOperationBehavior.

The requirement is to execute the validations in a particular order. But the order of execution doesn't seems to be consistent with the order the attributes are applied to the method.

```
[ValidationAttribute1]
[ValidationAttribute2]
public Student GetStudent(int Id){
}
```

Sometimes `ValidationAttribute2` gets executed before `ValidationAttribute1`. Is there a way we can enforce the order of execution in WCF?